# Python script to test password in multiple hosts at a time

Tags: python, linux, bash, authentication, scripting

I'm looking for a python script with worker concept that can test whether the standard password in my environment is authenticating with multiple hosts. My requirement is to authenticate all the linux hosts say more than 1000 with my password "Password1" for the user root and write the output to a text file that I can refer to find out the hosts that doesn't have root access with the standard password. Since the number of hosts are huge, password check should do in parallel and not one by one host.

Comment: You should turn off root access via SSH http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82626/why-is-root-login-via-ssh-so-bad-that-everyone-advises-to-disable-it - Alternatively, your generated list is useful for anyone looking for access to your servers

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear in my question. I don't have any concerns over security. Just need to find out the list of servers that work with my password. Planning to use Python to complete the checking faster and in parallel